# VBA EDITOR quits (terminates) Excel 2016 on mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am using MAC OS Mojave 10.14 and Excel version 16.19. I am trying to use the VBA  editor to create macros. However, whenever I insert a userform and try to change its properties (such as color, font, etc.) **or** when I  click on an object to complete the word by using list constants, Excel terminates itself and gives this error.

[image: ERROR due to usage of VBA Editor]

Is there any reason for (or a possible solution to) this problem?

Comment: This looks like it should be a bug report on a Microsoft site, there's not much to chew on for the SO community here.

Answer (score 2):

The version you provided means you have Office 2019, not Office 2016.

The ability to insert and edit userforms is not yet supported. Microsoft accidentally turned this capability on for a few users, but the feature isn't even ready for testing, yet. It will come along pretty soon, though, as you can see that quite a bit of the interface is built.